# Configure jerseys logging using ApacheHttpClient

Tags: java, logging, jenkins, log4j

I'm using jersey 1.19 with ApacheHttpClient 4.4 to consume a REST-API.

The application that uses this is using log4j 2.2

The problem I encounter is that jersey is logging every request multiple times which makes the console-output quite huge (its saved by jenkins).

jersey is used in a jar that is referenced by the main application.

I'm just trying to configure jersey to not dump that much output.

I know that its not using log4j, but I did not manage to get the SLF4JBridgeHandler to work:

```
java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("global").setLevel(Level.FINEST);

 java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("").log(Level.INFO, "Initialized SLF4JBridge");
```

It says

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for 
further details.
```

And its not printing "Initialized SLF4JBridge", but it still dumps everything from jersey.

Neither was I able to get a logging.properties file to work, it just ignores the file.

Whatever I try it just continues to dump everything to console...can anybody help?